# Is it possible to enforcing type of function params with boost::spirit QI

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm writing the parser to parse a list of built in functions.  For example:

`Function1(int p1, string p2)`

`Function2(string p1, int p2, string p3)`

`Function3(string p1, string p2, int p3, int p4, string p5)`
etc.

I don't have any issue writing rule to parse these functions individually like create AST struct for each then write rule to parse them like the below for **Function1** rule:

```
func1_ = lit("Function1") >> '(' >> int_ >> ',' >> literal_ >> ')';
```

But this function list is quite long so I will hit the limitation of allow variant.  I'm thinking of just create a single AST struct to parse all of them like this:

```
struct FunctionTemplate {
  std::string name;
  std::vector<boost::variant<int, std::string>> params
};
```

For simplicity, I'm just using **int** and **string** as param's types.

And for the rule, I could do:

```
params_ = int_ | literal_;
func_tpl_ = 
  (raw["Function1"] >> '(' >> (params_ % ',') >> ')')
  | (raw["Function2"] >> '(' >> (params_ % ',') >> ')')
  ;
```

It parsed just fine but this rule will also allow wrong param's datatype order as for ***Function1***, it will also accept **string** then **int** instead of the other way around. This will also accept more params then it should.

So is it possible to **enforce the param's datatype order** and **number of params** so that it not only parse correctly but also match the right order and right number of the params?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You enforce it in the grammer, or otherwise as semantic analysis, often after syntactic parsing.

Answer (score 0):

> But this function list is quite long so I will hit the limitation of allow variant. I'm thinking of just create a single AST struct to parse all of them like this

You can write your grammar productions like you intend, just make it so that the arguments get parsed into a common datatype (e.g. `numbers` instead of `int_` directly, with number as a `rule<It, MyArgType>`. That way you can parse into a generic (non-variant) datatype while still following different productions for different names.

In fact, for extensibility/maintainability you might use the Nabialek Trick here and store individual functions in separate rules of the same declared attributes. I must have a number of examples on this site that will probably show you some scriptlike grammars with a very similar approach.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll look into Nabialek Trick to see if any good example to achieve what I want.  If you happen to have the link, please let me know.  For the top section of your answer, I don't see how this would solve the enforce order of param's type.  I want to parse and only accept **Function1(int, literal)**  But the rule I have could also accept **Function1(literal, int, ... int, string)**  Did you mean I should create each struct for each function?

Comment: No, you specifically told us you didn't want that